# web2py: How to implement a ON DELETE RESTRICT

Tags: web2py

How to implement an ON DELETE RESTRICT on web2py, that is, if a parent record which is referenced by some child records is attempted for deletion, that action should be restricted or not allowed?

I'm referring to the Field construction with keyword on_delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `ondelete` argument to whatever you want:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('myfield', 'reference othertable', ondelete='RESTRICT'),
    ...)
```

Keep in mind that will simply cause the database driver to raise an exception when a prohibited delete is attempted, so you'll also want to have code in your application that (a) catches those exceptions or (b) prevents such deletes before attempted (and notify the user accordingly).

Comment: Can you provide some sample code or pseudo code for (a) and (b) please? There is not much available in the internet.

Comment: and btw, it seems there is no ondelete in the define_table function, only in the Field constructor.

Comment: Corrected the answer. Sample code for (a) and (b) is beyond the scope of the question and would be application specific. Better to give it a shot and ask a new question with specifics.